# Grammar-Kit: how to handle comment tokens

Tags: intellij-idea, jflex, grammar-kit

From the documentation provided for grammar-kit, I cannot figure out how I am supposed to correctly handle something like comments. My lexer currently returns `TokenType.WHITE_SPACE` for any comment blocks, but then no unique `IElementType` is generated for me to do syntax highlighting on.

If I create an `IElementType` and tell flex to return that for comments, I can perform syntax highlighting, but then that token is not a part of my language spec in the BNF, and so it is considered invalid.

[image]

What is the correct way to pass comments through as white space, but perform syntax highlighting on them in Intellij/grammar-kit/jflex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Grammar-Kit implementation as a reference:

1. [Lexer](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/src/org/intellij/grammar/parser/_BnfLexer.flex#L57)
2. [Grammar](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/grammars/Grammar.bnf#L45)
3. [ParserDefinition](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/src/org/intellij/grammar/BnfParserDefinition.java#L75)

Using `TokenType.WHITE_SPACE` for comments is a bad idea.

More details can be [found here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/implementing_parser_and_psi.html).